# Android, service, isolatedprocess, define permission

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, manifest

I am going to use an intent service in an Android application for downloading an image from the internet.

I have defined my intent service in Manifest file and I have set the             `android:isolatedProcess="true"` for that also. Now, in my intent service as I need to connect to the internet, my service need to has internet connection and also read and write on external storage permissions. As you know the isolated processes have no permission in android application.

Question: How can I define these permissions for my Intent service?

Comment: I don't think that you can, directly. `isolatedProcess` is for cases where you want to do something in a process that has no permissions (e.g., sandbox for a JavaScript interpreter).

Comment: So there is no way to do that you mean?

Comment: Correct. Using an `IntentService` to download an image feels like overkill, unless this is a rather large image. Forking an entire separate process to download an image is overkill.

Comment: Do you have any sense about implementation of this paper?https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity15/sec15-paper-backes.pdf

Comment: I fail to see what that paper has to do with downloading an image.

Comment: Actually the paper is not about the downloading an image, But is about running different applications inside separated processes. I wanna to use their ideas and honestly I wanna to implement their idea. There is no implementation of the paper's idea on the internet and I do not know how can I implement that.

Comment: That paper is presenting a very advanced (and kinda scary) project. Unless you are a very experienced developer (Java and C/C++, knowing your way around Binder and syscall hooking, etc.), you will have a very difficult time implementing what they propose. Coming up with something that works and is reliable might well be impossible. With respect to your question, the isolated process is not doing the download; the container app (Boxify, I guess) is doing that, presumably through syscall hooking.

Comment: FWIW, I wrote [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/17/droidception.html) discussing the Boxify app described in the paper that you cited.

Comment: Thanks for your post @CommonsWare, I read that. I think the main challenge in implementing the Boxify app is hooking Android API and system calls. Do you have any idea about hooking an application's APIs? I think if we can hook the Android APIs which the application is invoking, we can do other parts of Boxify app.

Comment: Sorry, but that is outside the scope of this question, and it is outside of the scope of what I would assist with on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So can you send me your email or how can I contact with you about my problem? I can not use chat here because I am a new user!

Comment: @Stateless It's been a long time. Did you got any luck or is there any alternative approach ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a similar requirement with android:isolatedProcess=false but with restricted private data directory access. Do you have any suggestions? The link to the detailed question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67399778/1643992