# How to impose private data directory access restrictions for Android services of the same app?

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, file-permissions

I would like to run an Android-app with two services using 'service' tag.

```
<service android:name=".Service1" android:process=":myprocess1"></service> 
<service android:name=".Service2" android:process=":myprocess2"></service>
```

The internal data directory looks something similar to below

```
 com.my.android.app
 -> data
    -> service1dir
    -> service2dir
```

PS: In the emulator it is hosted in /data/user/0/com.my.android.app

The invoking android-app has full permissions to the 'data' directory.
Is it possible to restrict permissions for the 'service1dir' directory to 'service1', 'service2dir' directory 'service2' services?

By doing so, I could achieve isolation with data storage and inet without setting android:isolatedProcess="true".
If I make the services as an isolated process both the services doesn't have inet/data/storage permissions.

Reference to [Android, service, isolatedprocess, define permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703331/android-service-isolatedprocess-define-permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to restrict permissions for the 'service1dir' directory to 'service1', 'service2dir' directory 'service2' services?

No, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. May be a prospect for a new feature?

Comment: @Raaam: It certainly seems worth you filing a feature request for it.